# post fla to youtube

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, youtube-api

may i know is it possible to post fla file pro grammatically to youtube? can elaborate how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this is a very broad question and YouTube doesn't accept FLAs or SWFs, only Flash Video or other forms of video. There are ways to access the YouTube APIs (http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html) with ActionScript and that might allow a flash program to upload a video programmatically. There is also Filmstrip (http://labs.animoto.com/2009/06/07/presenting-filmstrip/) which allows you to dynamically generate videos from your flash programs which you could upload.